# What crime have we committed?

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, language, geography

> We start in a city that rhymes with angina,
>   the masculine form, add in what's drunk in China,
>   then take phylum's first six, of the minor kind,
>   components will make what in our hand we find.
>
> We add to our hand where we initiated,
>   and what's in between, plus the two lower-rated,
>   now, this combination leads straight to a street,
>   we keep going southwards till we know we're beat.

What violent crime have we committed?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Following on from NudgeNudge who got halfway with

> Ace - which is what is in our hand

This can be shortened to

> A (this is just the standard abbreviation, and what is on the corner of the card)

Adding where we initiated

> AQ (Regina = Queen = Q)

Whats inbetween and the two lower rated

> A K Q J 10

this combination leads straight to a street

> This is a **broadway** straight in poker (assuming it's not a royal flush, I guess)

we keep going southwards till we know we're beat

> Following broadway southwards in Manhattan leads to **Battery** park

So the answer is

> Battery

Comment: why did you shorten in the second step? Doesn't change the next steps but still curious.

Comment: OK I understand now. Maybe you want to put a bit less spoilers in the comment or use rot13

Comment: @findusl - I put a brief explanation of the abbreviation in the answer itself no and deleted the comment with spoilers in.

Answer (score 44):

Partial:

We start in a city that rhymes with angina,

> **[Regina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regina,_Saskatchewan)**

the masculine form,

> Regina is *queen* in latin, and king is **rex**.

add in what's drunk in China,

> Tea, so **t-rex**

then take phylum's first six,

> The phylum of t-rexes is chordata. First six letters are **chord a**.

of the minor kind,

> That is, the **Am chord**.

components will make what in our hand we find.

> The components of the Am chord are the notes A, C, E. So there's an **ace** in our hand?

Comment: rot13 - V guvax gur ynfg yvar bs gur svefg irefr zrnaf gur pubeq "N" zvabe. Nabgure gubhtug: Gur "N" zvabe pubeq vf znqr hc bs gur abgrf n, p naq r be Npr va gur unaq (be hc gur fyrrir)

Comment: @pirate Yeah, I was thinking that too. I'll add it, thanks! :)

Comment: +1 in deep respect!